# Understanding function execution order in Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I was going through the code for [mergesort](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-merge-sort-3205891ac060), which uses recursion. I am a bit confused about how the code works. Since the confusion is regarding recursion, I am placing similar code below, which is much simplified and focuses just on the recursion part:

```
var index = 0;

function parent() {
  console.log("parent called");
  if(index < 5) {
  index++;
  return child(parent()); 
  }
  else return 1;
}

function child() {
  console.log("child called"); 
}

parent();
```

Above code outputs:

```
"parent called"
"parent called"
"parent called"
"parent called"
"parent called"
"parent called"
"child called"
"child called"
"child called"
"child called"
"child called"
```

I was expecting a "child called" after each "parent called", since `parent` calls `child` each time unless `index` becomes more than or equal to 5. So after the first call to `parent`, `parent` calls `child`, which *then* calls `parent`, and so on. So why is the output showing five successive "parent called" and then five successive "child called"?

I tried to understand it with a visualizer for call stack in JS, but I still didn't understand why `child` just puts the `parent` in stack, but itself is not executed at that time? You can see it in action [here](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=dmFyIGluZGV4ID0gMDsKICAgIAogICAgZnVuY3Rpb24gcGFyZW50KCkgewogICAgICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygicGFyZW50IGNhbGxlZCIpOwogICAgICBpZihpbmRleCA8IDMpIHsKICAgICAgaW5kZXgrKzsKICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIGNoaWxkKHBhcmVudCgpKTsgCiAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgZWxzZSByZXR1cm4gMTsKICAgIH0KICAgIAogICAgZnVuY3Rpb24gY2hpbGQoKSB7CiAgICAgIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCJjaGlsZCBjYWxsZWQiKTsgCiAgICB9CiAgICAKICAgIHBhcmVudCgpOwo%3D!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
child(parent());
```

It has to execute `parent()` to know what value to send to `child`.  So it keeps calling `parent` until it gets to the `else return 1;`, then keeps passing the return value to `child`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> child(parent());
> ```

`parent` has to be called *and finished* before it returns a value that can be passed to `child`.

So the first `parent` is called, it gets to the second `child(parent())` link and recursively calls the second `parent` which gets to the third `child(parent())` and so on until something returns `1` and that can be passed to `child`.